# Bitwise representation into a byte array function

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to do a memory writing program with bits as part of a CPU simulating program and I don't understand something. I'm making a function to write `int` value into the memory which is `byte` double array broken down into segments. Now, I don't understand why the following `writeWord` function is not working probably, I'll post relevant code as well as the function.

```
public class RealMemory implements Memory {
    public static final int BYTES_PER_INT = 4;
    public static final int BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;
    private final int segmentSize;
    private final int numberOfSegments; 

    private byte[][] memory;
    
    public RealMemory (int segmentSize, int numberOfSegments) {
        this.segmentSize = segmentSize;
        this.numberOfSegments = numberOfSegments;
        this.memory = new byte[this.numberOfSegments][this.segmentSize];
    }

    private byte[] getSegment(int segment) {
        assert(segment >= 0 && segment < numberOfSegments);
        return memory[segment];
    }

    public void writeWord (int segment, int offset, int value) {
        assert (offset >= 0 && offset < segmentSize - BYTES_PER_INT
             && offset % BYTES_PER_INT == 0);
        byte[] byteword = new byte[BYTES_PER_INT];
        int mask = 1;
        for (int i=offset; i < offset + BYTES_PER_INT; i++) {
            byteword[i-offset] = (byte) (value & mask);
            mask <<= 1;
            getSegment(segment)[i]=byteword[i-offset];
        }
    }
}
```

I know the way I try to breakdown the value into bits is wrong, I just don't understand bitwise operation needed here fully is my guess. Any help?

Comment: Do you know if the hardware system into which you are writing bits is Big-Endian or Little-Endian?

Comment: *not working probably* isnt a proper problem description. Please read [mcve], and add **expected** vs **actual** behavior of your code. As in: give us a static void main for example that invokes the method, and tell us what you think it should print INSTEAD of what it is actually printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `mask = 1`. You don't read bytes, but single bits instead.

To read bytes, use `int mask = (1 << BITS_PER_BYTE) - 1;` and  `mask <<= BITS_PER_BYTE;`. Once you masked out the relevant parts you also have to shift it to the right. As Stanislav Bashkyrtsev suggested, this can be done directly on the `value` instead of shifting the mask.

```
int mask = (1 << BITS_PER_BYTE) - 1;
for (int i=offset; i < offset + BYTES_PER_INT; i++) {
    byteword[i-offset] = (byte) (value & mask);
    value >>= BITS_PER_BYTE;
    getSegment(segment)[i]=byteword[i-offset];
}
```

Comment: After applying the mask you also need to shift your 8bits right so that they always occupy 1st byte of integer. In which case I wonder whether the mask is needed at all. First shift left, then shift right - and there you go.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Oh right, thank you for the note. Another flaw in OP's code I didn't recognize.